# Ignore files keep appearing when commit

Tags: phpstorm

I have place some files in the Ignore files but when I do a commit for the whole project those some files keep appearing on the commit list.

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the reason way the files keep appearing when commit

Settings > Version Control > Ignored Files only affects files that have not been added yet. Did you add  workspace.xml to the repository? If yes, it will be commited despite  being added to ignore list